# @RequestBody not able to convert object derived from AES Encrypted String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption, servlet-filters

From client side am passing an **AES** encrypted String with Content Type text/plain.

The AES encrypted String is Decrypted before reaching the controller through a Filter.

**CustomEncryptedFilter**

```
@Component
@Order(0) 
public class CustomEncryptedFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomEncryptedFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.info("************** Encryption Filter - START ***********************");
        String encryptedString = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
        if (encryptedString != null && encryptedString.length() > 0) {

            byte[] decryptedString = new AESEncrytion().decrypt(encryptedString).getBytes();

            if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {

                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper 
                = new CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest,decryptedString);
                                                           
                logger.info("Content Type: {}", requestWrapper.getContentType());
                logger.info("Request Body: {}", IOUtils.toString(requestWrapper.getInputStream()));

                chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);

            } else {

                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }

        } else {

            logger.info("Request is Invalid or Empty");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

Here I will getting the current request body which is an AES encrypted String
then am decrypting it to convert into a String.

```
encrypted String - Ijwmn5sZ5HqoUPb15c5idjxetqmC8Sln6+d2BPaYzxA=
Original String  - {"username":"thivanka"}
```

After getting the decrypted String (Json object) i am appending it to the request body
by extending **HttpServletRequestWrapper**

```
public class CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper.class.getName());

    private ByteArrayInputStream requestBody;

    public CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, byte[] decryptedString) {
        super(request);
        try {
            requestBody = new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String headerName) {
        String headerValue = super.getHeader(headerName);
        if ("Accept".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
            return headerValue.replaceAll(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        } else if ("Content-Type".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
            return headerValue.replaceAll(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        }
        return headerValue;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Enumeration getHeaderNames() {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getRequest();

        List list = new ArrayList();

        Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            
            String headerName = (String) e.nextElement();
            String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);

            if ("Accept".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
                headerValue.replaceAll(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            } else if ("Content-Type".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
                headerValue.replaceAll(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            }
            list.add(headerName);
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(list);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Enumeration getHeaders(final String headerName) {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getRequest();

        List list = new ArrayList();

        Enumeration e = request.getHeaders(headerName);
        
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

            String header = e.nextElement().toString();

            if (header.equalsIgnoreCase(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)) {
                header = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
            }
            
            list.add(header);
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(list);
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        String contentTypeValue = super.getContentType();
        if (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE.equalsIgnoreCase(contentTypeValue)) {
            return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
        }
        return contentTypeValue;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestBody, "UTF-8"));
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ServletInputStream() {
            @Override
            public int read() {
                return requestBody.read();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Apart from adding the new request body am also changing the MediaType from **text/plain**
to **application/json** in order for my @RequestBody annotation to pick up the media type and
perform object conversion.

Here's my **Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/mobc")
public class HomeController {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName());
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> Message(@RequestBody LoginForm loginForm,HttpServletRequest request) { 
        
        logger.info("In Home Controller");
        logger.info("Content Type: {}", request.getContentType());
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(loginForm);
    }

}
```

**LoginForm Object (I removed the Getters/Setters for readability)**

public class LoginForm {

```
private String username;

private String password;
```

}

Unfortunately am getting the error. What am i doing wrong here.

```
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possible issue

I suppose that `IOUtils.toString(InputStream stream)` reads all bytes from the `InputStream`. But `InputStream` could be read only once.

Your logging statement

```
logger.info("Request Body: {}", IOUtils.toString(requestWrapper.getInputStream()));
```

Reads an `InputStream`, so Spring can't read it a second time. Try replacing `IOUtils.toString(requestWrapper.getInputStream())` with `new String(encryptedString, Charset.defaultCharset())`.

#### Other implementation proposal

You can implement custom `RequestBodyAdvice` which will decrypt the message and change headers if needed.

As from Spring's JavaDoc:

> Implementations of this contract may be registered directly with the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter or more likely annotated with @ControllerAdvice in which case they are auto-detected.

Here is an example implementation of advice that changes the first byte of a message to `{` and last byte to `}`. Your implementation can modify the message decrypting it.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class CustomRequestBodyAdvice extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = inputMessage.getBody()) {
            byte[] bytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();
            bytes[0] = 0x7b; // 0x7b = '{'
            bytes[bytes.length - 1] = 0x7d; // 0x7d = '}'
            return new CustomMessage(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), inputMessage.getHeaders());
        }
    }
}

class CustomMessage implements HttpInputMessage {

    private final InputStream body;
    private final HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    public CustomMessage(InputStream body, HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        this.body = body;
        this.httpHeaders = httpHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
        return this.body;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        return this.httpHeaders;
    }
}
```

Also, there is `supports` method that returns whether this `RequestBodyAdvice` should be called. In this example this method always returns `true`, but you can create custom annotation and check for its existence.

```
// custom annotation
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface AesEncrypted {}

// class: CustomRequestBodyAdvice
@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    return methodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(AesEncrypted.class);
}

// controller
@PostMapping("one")
String getDecrypted(@AesEncrypted @RequestBody Data data) {
    return data.value;
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your input. my header change and decryption are already working but isn't @Requestbody annotation suppose to automatically serialize since am already changing Accept header through  HttpServletRequestWrapper before passing it down to the controller ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please take a look

Comment: thank you for your implementation. Yes the data from the InputStream can be read only once that was the cause of this issue. I changed the RequestWrapper to a ContentCachingRequestWrapper which solved the problem. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with this then the answer is to move to a ContentCachingRequestWrapper. Other approach would be to use the aspect oriented variation suggested by @geobreze which solves the same question.

I just had to modify my HttpServletRequestWrapper to facilitate the change.

Refs -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times

> This class caches the request body by consuming the InputStream. If we
> read the InputStream in one of the filters, then other subsequent
> filters in the filter chain can't read it anymore. Because of this
> limitation, this class is not suitable in all situations.